# AlarmManager: don't fire past alarms

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I Have an app that show a notification every SATURDAY at 12.00 with

```
setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, findNextSaturday(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, showNotificationIntent);
```

Everything is fine, unless the user change the clock: if today is FRIDAY and the user set SUNDAY the notification appears but it's NOT SATURDAY!

There is a option of AlarmManager to NOT fire past alarms?
I know i can add some kind of check (like, it's saturday?) in the notification logic but i really prefear to not fire past alarm at all.

Thanks!

Comment: well what would be the difference if the user had the phone off for Saturday and turned it on sunday, that would also create the same effect. should the alarm not fire then too?

Comment: Sure! The alarm should NOT fire in that case, it's not SATURDAY 12.00! :)

Comment: so then just check the time or the day when it gets fired and dont do whatever it is if its not saturday

Comment: As i wrote... "I know i can add some kind of check (like, it's saturday?) in the notification logic but i really prefear to not fire past alarm at all."
So there aren't alternatives?

Comment: no there is not because